# Chrome Developer Tools network request reports excessive response time

Tags: apache, codeigniter, http, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Using the Chrome network panel, I find that I have one request which keeps returning as 16027.6 days long. Considering how that's longer than my entire life so far, that seems excessive.

[image: Network Request]

Request headers:

```
GET /performance/login/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.92
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: https://192.168.2.92/performance/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: PHPSESSID=qu9e2tbjn98mge14ifpkqf7go4;     cw=ee2da41084f3ebaa9012f1120558e4faee99d0e8;     session=a%3A8%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%2270de4726ca6e81e779947f11327c492a%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22192.168.2.92%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3 Bs%3A108%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F31.0.1650.57+Safari%2F537.36%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1384802015%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22user%22%3Ba%3A8%3A%7Bs%3A2%3A%22id%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22731%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22username%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22support_m%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22name%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22Mark%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22email%22%3Bs%3A31%3A%22moberemk%40publicsectordigest.com%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22admin%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22perf_db%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22perf_kenn%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22client%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22Kennedale%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22client_id%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22731%22%3B%7Ds%3A9%3A%22logged_in%22%3Bb%3A1%3Bs%3A15%3A%22app_preferences%22%3Ba%3A2%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22trend_period%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%226%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22trend_unit%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22months%22%3B%7D%7D65fd2545afa3a2c283d575b9278fbb1c
```

Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 18 Nov 2013 19:17:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.7
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie:     session=a%3A8%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%2270de4726ca6e81e779947f11327c492a%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22192.168.2.92%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A108%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F31.0.1650.57+Safari%2F537.36%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1384802015%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22user%22%3Ba%3A8%3A%7Bs%3A2%3A%22id%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22731%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22username%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22support_m%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22name%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22Mark%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22email%22%3Bs%3A31%3A%22moberemk%40publicsectordigest.com%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22admin%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22perf_db%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22perf_kenn%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22client%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22Kennedale%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22client_id%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22731%22%3B%7Ds%3A9%3A%22logged_in%22%3Bb%3A1%3Bs%3A15%3A%22app_preferences%22%3Ba%3A2%3A%7Bs%3A12%3A%22trend_period%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%226%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22trend_unit%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22months%22%3B%7D%7D65fd2545afa3a2c283d575b9278fbb1c; expires=Mon, 18-Nov-2013 21:17:42 GMT; path=/
Status: 200
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 153
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=90
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

I'm not sure exactly what my web server is doing to trigger this, so I'm thinking this might be a Chrome-specific bug. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a time issue. Check the date on both local and remote machines. That response time is pretty close to the days since epoch which would indicate for some reason the server thinks it's 1970.

If you go to http://www.epochconverter.com/ copy the epoch time at the top (something like 1384805814), enter it in "Convert seconds to days, hours and minutes", you will get something like "16027 days, 20 hours, 16 minutes and 17 second" which is pretty close to what you're seeing in the console.

It's strange, though, to see Date in the response headers as correct and at the same time an expire for sometime in 1981...almost as if webserver is using one date and php is using another.

The solution will depend on what the stack you are using is. https://serverfault.com/ would be a better place to ask for help with the issue.

Comment: The issue is that this is my local machine--I'm accessing my own XAMPP server here. The issue also doesn't exist in any other browser I've checked.

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug in chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=319705 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=309570 That said, in the future, serverfault.com would be a better bet for questions like this. SO is intended for problems with your code, not someone else's :)

Comment: Yeah, I had a representative tweet me regarding this late last night--I guess it's something they're aware of and working on. I wasn't sure if it was a problem on my end or the program though so I put it here--thanks for the head's up!